# why does the following Javascript code loop infinitely?

Tags: javascript

I am trying use Javascript `continue` statement inside the while loop but it loops infinitely

Can you explain me?

```
var john = ['john', 'smith', 1990, 'designer', false, 'blue' ];

var i = 0;
while ( i < john.length) {
    if( typeof john[i] !== 'string') continue;
        console.log( john[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Calling `continue` skips the rest of the loop, including the `i++`, so once `i` is `2` the loops runs forever.

Comment: but I havê set a condition that only skip if the value is not string and there are condition how many times it's should loop

Comment: When `i` reaches `2`, `typeof john[i]` is `"number"` , so JS calls `continue`. The loop continues, but `i` is still `2`. Just use this instead: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jn8pwzmc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you use the keyword `continue` you are skipping the rest of the code below it and jumping back to the top of your `while` loop. This means that `i++` is never reached once you `continue`, and so, you will always be looking at the integer `1990` in your array. Thus `continue` will always be called as your if statement will be stuck looking like so:

```
if(typeof 1990 !=== 'string') { 
  // true so code will fire
  continue; // you reach continue so your loop runs again, running the same if statement check as you haven't increased 'i' (so it checks the same element)
}
// all code below here will not be run (as 'continue' is used above)
```

Instead, you need to increment in your `if` statement and outside of it. Allowing you to look at the next value in your array:

```js
var john = ['john', 'smith', 1990, 'designer', false, 'blue' ];

var i = 0;
while ( i < john.length) {
    if( typeof john[i] !== 'string') {
       i++; // go to next index
       continue;
     }
     console.log( john[i]);
     i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written `continue` before incrementing the value of `i`.

You should increment the value of `i` before `continue`, like so:

```
var john = ['john', 'smith', 1990, 'designer', false, 'blue' ];

var i = 0;
while ( i < john.length) {

    if( typeof john[i] !== 'string') {
       i++;
       continue;
    }  
    console.log( john[i]);
    i++;
}
```